# Undefined variable: template in /var/www/lamicall/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php on line 357

Tags: magento2, frontend

I got this error after change to using **client-side compilation mode**.

`Undefined variable: template in /var/www/lamicall/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php on line 357`

Comment: Did you Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and Cache Flush php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Yes, and I got another error

  [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXmdO.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following：

```
php.ini  

symlink() enable
```